# Install repository and sync project error(23,24), error(26,17), and install artifact and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, installation-package

[image]

I have tried reinstalling the setup several times. When I click on install, it's not showing any response, when I click on below lines `show file`, `show in project structure` dialog it's responding. I have checked for my network, it's working. I couldn't even find links on the Internet regarding these type of errors.